# Can I change pwd for each server, but different pwd for each from env object?

Tags: python, fabric

```
from fabric.api import env, task, run

env.passwords = {
    'avirgovic@host1.at:22': '5rFVChuEYp0cpuUjeg20',
    'avirgovic@host.com:22': 'cxvxxd410!@--/w'
}
env.hosts = ['host1.at', 'host2.com']
env.user = "avirgovic"


@task
def change_passwords():
    run("change password command")
```

I would like to change passwords of multiple server instances. But do not want to change all to the same one (my snippet is able to do this).Is there a way to define some object and use it as a set hint. For instance:

```
new_pwd_host_map = {
    "host1": "sfhsd554rwere",
    "host2": "dsfhgsdkg^^&516"
}
```

If not, what would you consider to be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a list whose keys are actual hosts and values are passwords for each of them; then, in your task, use the `env.host` as a key to get the new password for that specific host. Something like:

```
env.hosts = ['host1.com', 'host2.com']

new_passwords = {
    'host1.com': 'somepass',
    'host2.com': 'someotherpass'
}

@task
def changepass():
    sudo('change password command ' + new_passwords[env.host])
```